# JS: using object from parent class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having two classes and want to have an Object with values that are available for both classes. This is my sample code:

```js
class Class1 {
  
  constructor() {
   this.things = [];
   this.testValue = "one two three";
  }
  
  doThings() {
  
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.things[i] = "test "+i;
        }
    
    console.log("Class 1 doThings(): ", this.things);
  
  }
  
  getContent() {
      console.log("getContent Class1: ", this.things);
  }
  
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {

  constructor(elmnt){
    super();
  }
  
  getContent() {
      console.log("Class 2 getContent(): ", this.things);
  }
  
  getValue() {
    
    console.log("Value: ", this.testValue)
    
  }

}

let handle1 = new Class1();
let handle2 = new Class2();

handle1.getContent(); // empty because this.things() did not run
handle1.doThings(); // create things...
handle1.getContent(); // this shows the things

handle2.getContent(); // this is empty even is doThings() is called before to produce things...

handle2.getValue();
```

Why is handle2.getContent() not showing the Things-Array? And (more important) what would be right?

i think the super() overrides the this.things... Is that true? how could i prevent this?

Comment: when makes you think that calling methods on `handle2` will do anything at all to `handle1`? These are completely separate objects, and still would be even if they were both instantiated from the same class.

Comment: i think this is a good point. but how could i change ONE global array from both classes?

Comment: @user7213923 By creating only a single array, with a single object that is an instance of both classes! `const handle = new Class2(); console.log(handle instanceof Class1); handle.doThings(); handle.getContent();`

Answer (score 1):

Just because you ran `doThings()` in `handle1`, doesn't mean `doThings()` was run in `handle2`.
For you to get the output you want, you need to run `doThings()` in `handle2`

```js
class Class1 {
  
  constructor() {
   this.things = [];
   this.testValue = "one two three";
  }
  
  doThings() {
  
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.things[i] = "test "+i;
        }
    
    console.log("Class 1 doThings(): ", this.things);
  
  }
  
  getContent() {
      console.log("getContent Class1: ", this.things);
  }
  
}

class Class2 extends Class1 {

  constructor(elmnt){
    super();
  }
  
  getContent() {
      console.log("Class 2 getContent(): ", this.things);
  }
  
  getValue() {
    
    console.log("Value: ", this.testValue)
    
  }

}

let handle1 = new Class1();
let handle2 = new Class2();

handle1.getContent(); // empty because this.things() did not run
handle1.doThings(); // create things...
handle1.getContent(); // this shows the things

handle2.doThings() // This needs to run

handle2.getContent(); // this is empty even is doThings() is called before to produce things...

handle2.getValue();
```